# Covering a set with $N$ balls of common minimal(!) radius (Existence of such a covering)

Tags: functional-analysis, geometry, optimization, banach-spaces, reflexive-space

Let $X$ be a Banach space, and denote by $B_r (x)$ the closed ball of radius $r > 0$
around $x \in X$. Furthermore, let $A \subset X$ be compact and $N \in \Bbb{N}$.
I am interested in "optimally" covering $A$ by $N$ balls, i.e,. with as small radius as possible.
More precisely, define
$$
  r_0
  := \inf \Big\{
            r > 0
            \colon
            \exists \, x_1,\dots,x_N \in X \text{ such that } A \subset \bigcup_{i=1}^N B_r (x_i)
          \Big\},
$$
and assume that $r_0 > 0$.

> I would like to know whether there necessarily exist $x_1,\dots,x_N \in X$
>   such that $A \subset \bigcup_{i=1}^N B_{r_0} (x_i)$.
>   In other words, I would like to know if the infimum above is actually a minimum.

**Note** I am taking the $x_i$ from the "surrounding" space $X$, not from the compact set $A$.

I can prove the claim in case that $X$ is reflexive (even only assuming that $A$ is bounded),
but I am not sure whether it is true for more general Banach spaces.
I will give my proof for the reflexive case below, in case one can either generalize it,
or use it to get an idea for a counterexample.

---

---

**Proof for the reflexive case:**
Choose a sequence $r_n \to r_0$ such that for each $n$ there are  $x_1^n,\dots,x_N^n \subset X$
satisfying $A \subset \bigcup_{i=1}^N B_{r_n}(x_i^n)$.
If $B_{r_n} (x_i^n) \cap A = \emptyset$ for some $i,n$, replace $x_i^n$ by zero.
Note that this retains the property $A \subset \bigcup_{i=1}^N B_{r_n}(x_i^n)$.

Since $A$ and the sequence $(r_n)_{n}$ are bounded, there is $R > 0$ such that $\| x \| \leq R$
and $r_n \leq R$ for all $x \in A$ and $n \in \Bbb{N}$:
There are now two cases for each $i,n$:
1) There is some $x \in A \cap B_{r_n} (x_i^n)$,
   and hence $\| x_i^n \| \leq \| x_i^n - x \| + \| x \| \leq r_n + R \leq 2R$.
2) There is no $x \in A \cap B_{r_n} (x_i^n)$, and hence $x_i^n$, whence $\| x_i^n \| \leq 2R$.

Therefore, each of the sequences $(x_i^n)_{n \in \Bbb{N}} \subset X$ is bounded.
Since $X$ is assumed to be reflexive, we can choose a common subsequence
(which I will ignore in the notation below) such that $x_i^n \to x_i$ weakly for all $i = 1,\dots,N$.

Now, let $x \in A$ be arbitrary.
For each $n \in \Bbb{N}$, there is $i_n \in \{1,\dots,N\}$ satisfying $\| x - x_i^n \| \leq r_n$.
Next, there is $\ell \in \{1,\dots,N\}$ such that $i_n = \ell$ for infinitely many $n \in \Bbb{N}$,
say for $n = n_m$ with $n_m \to \infty$.
Since $x - x_i^{n_m} \to x - x_i$ weakly and since the norm is lower semicontinuous with respect
to weak convergence, we see that
$\| x - x_\ell \| \leq \liminf_{m \to \infty} \| x - x_i^{n_m} \| \leq \liminf_{m \to \infty} r_{n_m} = r_0$.
Since this holds for any $x \in A$, we get $A \subset \bigcup_{\ell=1}^N B_{r_0} (x_\ell)$,
as desired.

Comment: Have you figured out $N=1$?

Comment: @mathworker21: No, even that would be interesting.

Comment: @mathworker21  In any metric space $\text{diam}A$, the diameter of $A:=\sup \{ d(a_1,a_2) \mid a_1, a_2 \in A  \}$, is well defined.  In a complete metric space I believe this $\sup$ will be achieved.  If so, in the case $N=1$, the optimal $r$ should be $r_0=\text{diam}A / 2$.

Comment: @Selrach: I don't think this is actually true; see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2734808/smallest-ball-to-contain-a-subset-of-diameter-d-in-mathbbrn

Comment: @PhoemueX Aha, so Jung's Theorem gives us an upper bound on $r_0$. That means for $A$, a compact subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$, 
$\text{diam}A/2$ is just a lower bound.  Combining the bounds we have:
$$ \text{diam}A \cdot\frac{1}{2}\leq r_0 \leq \text{diam}A\sqrt{\frac{n}{2(n+1)}}$$
[Reason for the lower bound is $A \subseteq B_{r_0}$ which implies
$ \text{diam}A \leq \text{diam}B_{r_0}=2r_0 $.]

Comment: @PhoemueX doesn't my answer below answer your question?

Comment: @mathworker: Sorry, forgot to click that button. Thanks again for your answer!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't feel too bad posting a "proof by references" since I worked on this problem for quite a while but failed, before realizing the $N=1$ case seems pretty google-able. In any event, it seems Konyagin proved that any non-reflexive Banach space admits an equivalent norm and some 3 points so that there is no smallest ball with respect to the equivalent norm containing those 3 points. A good buzzword is "Chebyshev center". Below is a link to a strengthening of Konyagin's result (and a mention of Konyagin's result). I couldn't find a free version of Konyagin's paper online.

https://dml.cz/bitstream/handle/10338.dmlcz/119230/CommentatMathUnivCarolRetro_42-2001-1_11.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the infimum above is not actually a minimum.  To see this let $A$ be any two point set in $\mathbb{R}^2$.  Then $r_0=0$ whenever $N \geq 2$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Note, however, that I assume $r_0>0$ in my question.